# Reuse code of a method that inserts an array of objects

Tags: java, optimization, arraylist, design-patterns

I have a method that inserts a list of objects in the database:

```
public void insert(List<Object> objects){

}
```

Now, I need to insert a single object. I do not want to create a new method that does the insertion of a single object because it would duplicate a lot of code, so I do the following:

```
public void insert(Object object){
  List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
  objects.add(object);
  insert(objects);
}
```

I do not know if the above is correct, my knowledge of java is high level so I do not know how expensive it is for the system to convert the object to the arrangement and if this is a good development technique. Or if by some pattern or convention I must create a method to insert a single object.

Comment: *I do not know if the above is correct*: test it, and you'll know. Why do you think it could be incorrect? *I do not know how expensive it is*: creating an ArrayList compared to inserting something in a database is like walking to your kitchen compared to going to the moon (roughly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is method overloading and this is exactly the way to do this kind of a thing.

You can improve it though, by making it shorter and removing the unnecessary variable like this:-

```
public void insert(Object object){
  insert(Collections.singletonList(object));
}
```

One thing you can consider is whether to call `insert(List<Object> objects)` from within `insert(Object object)` or vice-versa. If you are iterating through the list and processing each element one by one, then it would be better to have your database insertion code in `insert(Object object)` and call this method for each element in `insert(List<Object> objects)`. Otherwise if you are passing the list to a library method as it is, then what you are doing is right.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing bad about your pattern. You can initialize the list in a smarter way though:

```
public void insert(Object object){
  insert(Arrays.asList(object));
}
```

Comment: Collections.singletonList() would be more appropriate.